# DotnetCore Custom S2i OpenShift Image

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, openshift, s2i

I am looking to create a custom S2i image for dotnetcore 3.1

I could not find much examples in OpenShift documentation

Can anyone provide some example reference of any custom image built for S2i in dotnetcore 3.1

Also looking on how to get this image to OpenShift so that it can be used in "oc new-app" command

Answer (score 1):

This is the source code for the official s2i images for .NET Core 3.1 that Red Hat builds https://github.com/redhat-developer/s2i-dotnetcore/tree/master/3.1

The s2i image is a regular container image. You can get it into OpenShift using any of the other ways you get container images into OpenShift. ImagesStreams might be a good way.

Comment: When we used a docker file to build image, I have my custom Image that I refer on top in a dockerfile, that image internally uses dotnet image, now how could I trigger the build in OpenShift using S2I ?, Should I write any custom script. Hope you understood my point